# Combinations of $5$ letters and $3$ numbers in an $8$ digit password

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm having a pretty hard time solving this relatively simple problem. Essentially, the problem asks how many 8 digit passwords can be formed using 5 different letters from a set of uppercase and lowercase letters (thus, $52$ letters in total) and $3$ different digits from the set of integers $0-9$. My solution so far is that there are $\binom{8}{5}\binom{52}{5}\binom{10}{3}$ possible passwords, but I have no way of checking is this is true and the other problems haven't come quite so easily to me. Am I correct? If not, how can I find the correct answer? Thank you!

Comment: You haven't accounted for the fact that letters and can be reordered. You need to multiply by $3!5!$.

Comment: Let us put an order on all $52$ letters, and the usual order on the $10$ digits. Given a password associate the following data: (1) extract the $5$ different letters from the password, write them in the given order in a list. (2) extract the $3$ different digits, put them in order, append them in this order to the list. We now have a list with the same characters as in the password. There is a unique permutation "mapping the extracted list into the password (order)". (3) record this permutation as part of the data. Conversely, each of these $\binom {52}5$ times $\binom{10}3$ times $8!$ ...

Comment: Your question is only in the title and is not clear. Does the question state that letters and numbers ($0$-$9$) are all different? Does it state uppercase /lowercase anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

It is said that $5$ distinct letters (uppercase and lowercase ) and $3$ distinct digits will be used to construct lenght of $8$. So , lets assume that there are $8$ spaces to fill with characters.

Lets choose $5$ spaces among $8$ spaces to place the letters by $\binom{8}{5}$ , so the rest will be for digits.

It is also said that letters and digits must be different , so we can use permutatiton. Permutation for letters is $P(52,5)$ , permutation for digits is $P(10,3)$

Hence , the result is $$\binom{8}{5} \times P(52,5) \times P(10,3)  $$

Comment: It would be better to use the word spaces rather than gaps since gaps are spaces between objects.